# very old CPU INTEL 8086 + 8087 EMBEDDED system Intel IC-86 Compiler

Tags: embedded, intel, x86-16, x87, retro-computing

It was old challenge for me but I have succeed to build my own embedded system based on a 80188 INTEL ( like 8086). I am using the compiler C 4.5 from Intel. As I want to go further I would like to integrate the 8087 coprocessor.
This technology is older that 40 years...

Before spending time to wire the 8087 on by board I am trying to use the 8087 emulator given by the compiler. IC-86 version 4.5 from INTEL.

I cannot find the way to link the E87.lib and relocate the library in my project.
Does someone could share examples of link/relocate using a 8087 on an embedded system?

Sounds that the libraries given for the 8087  can't be relocated in the 20-bits addresses?

Comment: It will be down to your linker - do you have a manual?  Why do you need to explicitly locate the library in any case?

Comment: Note also that not all 80188 variants ar compatible with teh 8087. What is your specific part variant?  80C188 is not 8087 compatible while N80188 is.

Comment: Have you considered using DOSBox or something to emulate a 386 + 387 to test your code?  There are some differences between a 386 in real mode vs. an 8086 or 186, like `#DE` exceptions on 8086 push the address *after* the faulting `div`, instead of the divide instruction itself. But anyway, perhaps you'd have better luck asking on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ if you can provide more details on exactly what you're trying to do with software, where you downloaded things from, and what doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have got the complete documentation (linker)  from INTEL.  The hardware  and the linker are also compatible. The problem occurs whenever I  want to use the locator ( fixing the physical addresses  in order to burn an eprom). The distribution software is giving an example for embedded software using a 64K space for data and code. In my homemade project I am using 64 of data and 64 of    program. The issue  is to fix the location of the math libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your support.  The hardware and  software are compatible. My main concern is to be able to link the math libraries with my own code to burn the eprom. To achieve this I need to be able to specify were the math lib must be located in the memory. I would like that the math libraries be linked with my code from the address F0000H.  The library E87.LIB emulate the 8087 and some interrupt are assigned to the vector interrupts. This is why I decided to find people having experience in this very hold systems. Thank you all